# Navigation Bottom Bat didn't work when I press one time in the icons, it works only when i press two times?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I use fragment for every icon in the bottom navigation bar and if i press two times  on the icon (it doesn't matter which is) fragment it shows, if I pres in another icon two (2) times the next fragment it comes etc... But if i press only one time in the icons the fragments doesn't appears.
BTW I am using Android Studio.

How can i solve problem? I want with one click in the icon to show the fragment.

At menu folder into res, i create a XML file with 5 items like below:

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
 android"xmlns:app="http://schmas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/pref"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/pref"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
    />
 </menu>
```

The activity file in XML which is connect to Java class is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:contextClickable="false"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigacion"
    android:id="@+id/frame"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigacion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/color_nav_bar"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contextClickable="false"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/navigacion"
            android:id="@+id/frame"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add below materiel dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with my bottom_nav_menu.xml file ,so I created a new nav file it worked for me.